# Brotherhood of steel in Fallout NV

Tags: fallout-new-vegas

I prefer the brotherhood to the NCR, but have been helping them because I don't mind them 
. I have been given a quest to destroy the brotherhood but I would rather destroy the NCR. I have talked to everyone I can think of I'm the B. O. S. but no one is giving me a chat option that isn't idle chat.  How do I side with the brotherhood against the NCR?

Comment: Have you completed the quest _Still in the Dark_?

Comment: which one is that?

Comment: First quest you get from the BOS, ultimately deals with an air filtration system. Should be able to see if it's completed in your quest log.

Comment: Also, there's a way to resolve things peacefully between the NCR and the BOS. Do you want to do that, or completely side against the NCR?

Comment: I wouldn't mind siding them together.

Comment: If that's the case, and Elder McNamara won't talk to you, try waiting for 2-3 days outside the bunker, then re-enter it. He should talk to you then.

Comment: Related: [I've heard about negotiating a treaty between the NCR and BoS. Is it true?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/16546/108003)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There isn't really a way to side against the NCR *with* the Brotherhood -- Instead, you have the following options:

- Broker a truce between the NCR and B.O.S.
- Destroy the B.O.S.
- Ignore the NCR quest to destroy the B.O.S. and side with a different main faction (Yes Man or Legion, since House is taken care of at this point), while continuing the B.O.S questline

To broker a truce, you must **not** have ousted Elder McNamara during the quest *Still in the Dark*. When the NCR gives you the quest to destroy the B.O.S., and you've finished *Still in the Dark*, go talk to Elder McNamara and tell him that the NCR wants to destroy them. That will prompt McNamara to propose a truce. If you've finished *Still in the Dark* and Elder McNamara won't talk to you, try waiting outside the bunker for 2-3 days, then re-entering and talking to him again (known bug).

If you ousted McNamara, the only way to make a truce between the B.O.S. and the NCR is through the following console command, which makes the game think that the Elder offered a truce: `SetObjectiveDisplayed 136166 56 1`

Comment: what if it's Hardin.

Comment: @Sparta270 Then you can't broker a truce. You have to pick one of the other two options I listed. Destroy the Brotherhood, or side with another main faction (not the NCR)

Comment: @Sparta270 Did this answer your question? I'm worried I misunderstood, or that you were looking for different information.

Comment: well that sucks...  Yeah ig that's what I was looking for.

Comment: Sorry I didn't have better news for you :( I know this game like the back of my hand, and those are 100% your only options (without console commands, of course).

Comment: thank you, I wish the B. O. S.  had more pull in the game.

Comment: @Sparta270 Same. Also, I'm editing the answer to include the console command to force a truce, even with Hadrin as the Elder (in case that helps).